# LINQ to SQL - Delete Many to Many if no relations

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table that store "Tags" like so:

```
ProductTags
    TagID     PK           
    Name      nvarchar(50) [not null]
```

and a M2M map table like this:

```
ProductTagMap
    ProductID PK
    TagID     PK
```

Now let's say I remove a tag relationship (or all of them) from a Product like so:

```
 // get our Product we are working on...
 Product product = dataContext.Products.Where(p > p.ProductID = 1);

 // this remove the link between the product and its tags
 dataContext.ProductTagMaps.DeleteAllOnSubmit(product.ProductTagMaps);

 //*** If these product-specific Tag/s is/are no longer used ***/
 //*** by any other Products I'd like to delete them         ***/
 //*** How can this be done here?                            ***/

 dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

If *these* Tags (that were/are related to the specific product) are no longer related to any Products I'd like them to be deleted.
How can this be done in the code above (see the comment)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that would require checking for other mappings in other records, you'd have to do a query to check for orphans:

```
var tags =    from t in dataContext.Tags
    where t.ProductTags.Count() == 0
    select t;
dataContext.Tags.DeleteAllOnSubmit(tags);
```

And this gives you the tags you can delete.